# what is the alternative for the deprecated cachemanager class in android

Tags: android, caching

I see that cachemanager is a deprecated class in Android sdk. So what is the substitiute of cachemanager. I see a way with the data storage techniques. but how are they supposed to implement the cache algorithm. Does everyone has to write there own Cachemanagers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what kind of cache you are looking for. ICS adds a built-in HTTP response cache, see this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for more info.

If you are looking for a more general disk cache then the ICS source code has a nice class called DiskLruCache (not available in the public APIs though). It has been back ported and released by a 3rd party though: [DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache).